# Problema com acentos, C# App Console

Tags: c#, codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação, stream-de-arquivos

Lê e grava o arquivo

```
 public void LereGravar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - Processamento Iniciado, Lendo Arquivo");

        //Procura dentro da Pasta
        DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(LerArquivos);
        FileInfo[] Files = Dir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var conteudoArquivo = new List<ArquivoTxt>();
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in Dir.GetFiles())
        {
            using (StreamReader leitor = fi.OpenText()) 
            {
                while (!leitor.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var linha = new ArquivoTxt();
                    linha.Linha = leitor.ReadLine();
                    conteudoArquivo.Add(linha);
                }
            }

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Carteira_Vendas, true, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
            conteudoArquivo = conteudoArquivo.Where(_ => _.Linha.StartsWith("|") &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|O" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|-" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|C" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|I" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|T" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "| " &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|R" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|D" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|E").ToList();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - Processamento finalizado");

            foreach (var item in conteudoArquivo)
            {
                string[] linha = item.Linha.Split('|');
                string ordemVenda = linha[1].Trim();
                sw.WriteLine(TiraAcentuacao(item.Linha));
            };
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Deveria tirar retirar os acentos**

```
        static string TiraAcentuacao(string StringAcentuada)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringAcentuada.Trim()))
            return string.Empty;
        else
        {
            byte[] array = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-8").GetBytes(StringAcentuada);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
        }
    }
```

**Retorno da Linha que recebo**

> |2021552949    |000018                     |0001                    |MTO       |ZNOR            |1182042         |3A ALUMINIO INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO EI|1182042               |3A ALUMINIO INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO EI|6155211         |ES E13152 6063 T5 6000 N-CG             |4500017089                         |     1.381,000 |KG            |       3.908,230 |         3.908,230 |         0,000 |CN            |                2.614,375 |                   0,000 |                  0,000 |       0,000 |26.12.2017        |2020       |C              |30.06.2018|24.08.2018        |24.08.2018     |22.08.2018         |23.08.2018           |             |2100                 |OUTROS CC      |ESN0300          |EXTRUDADO NATURAL             |Conjuga??o De Carga |                           |SIM            |Extrudados        |BLEANDROGG   |2SP156    |SP-ALUM?NIO/SP-JANDIRA              |CIF-Jandira - SP              |               0,000 |                     6.000,00|2020              |

Meu retorno é (?) no lugares do acentos, oque poderia fazer para ele gravar o acento ou simplesmente ignora-lo.

Comment: Se fizer apenas o `sw.WriteLine(item.Linha);` não grava com os acentos?

Comment: Não, já tentei, ele substitui os acentos por ponto de interrogação.

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou normal. Não entendo muito de encoding, mas talvez seja essa transição que está causando o problema. Tenta usando esse método: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3VwlPV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente da seguinte forma:

```
using System.Text;

public void LereGravar()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - Processamento Iniciado, Lendo Arquivo");

    var files = Directory.GetFiles("LerArquivos", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var conteudoArquivo = new List<ArquivoTxt>();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using (StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
        {
            while (!leitor.EndOfStream)
            {
                var linha = new ArquivoTxt() { Linha = leitor.ReadLine() };
                conteudoArquivo.Add(linha);
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Carteira_Vendas, true, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
        {
            conteudoArquivo = conteudoArquivo.Where(_ => _.Linha.StartsWith("|") &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|O" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|-" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|C" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|I" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|T" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "| " &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|R" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|D" &&
                                                 _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|E").ToList();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - Processamento finalizado");

            foreach (var item in conteudoArquivo)
            {
                string[] linha = item.Linha.Split('|');
                string ordemVenda = linha[1].Trim();
                sw.WriteLine(item.Linha);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alterei um pouco o seu código, acho que não há necessidade de utilizar o `FileInfo` quando pode abrir o ficheiro a partir do `Path`.

A alteração mais "crítica" foi utilizar o `StreamReader` com o `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`, assim como o `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Não funcionou continua me retornando sem acentuação no lugar o "?"

Comment: No ficheiro original os acentos estão corretos ou já vem com o caracter "?"?

Comment: está correto no original, ao regravar ele fica sem acentuação.

Comment: Pois, o UTF-8 não trata os acentos corretamente. Resposta editada para ao invés de utilizar o UTF-8 utilizar o ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Não se esqueça de dar o UP na resposta ;)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!!